# Python - convert .txt content into json format

Tags: python, json

```
Name: Donald J. Trump
Username: @realDonaldTrump
Post: I look forward to paying my respects to our brave men and women on this Memorial Day at Arlington National Cemetery later this morning.
post's link: https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/869170615881793536
Replies: 16,259 replies
Retweet: 15,103 retweets
Likes: 90,839 likes
Date: 5:36 AM - 29 May 2017
```

Hi all, above is the format of each chunk of data in my first.txt file. I would like to read it and change it to to the json format like the one below, and store it to second.txt file.

```
def convert_to_json(path, name, username, post, link, replies, retweets, likes, retweetby, date, domainname):
with open(path, 'a') as file:
    stringData = [{"ContentUrl": link,
    "Text": post,
    "PublishDate": date.strip(),
    "Title": "",
    "SourceUrl": domainname,
    "SocialNetwork": media,
    "Source": "",
    "Author": name,
    "Like_count": likes.strip(),
    "Replies_count": replies.strip(),
    "Retweets_count": retweets.strip(),
    "Schema": "SOCIAL_MEDIA"}]

    objData = json.load(stringData)
    file.write(stringData)
```

The above code was suppose to take in data and then append it to second.txt file. However, my code did not manage to append the data i want into my second.txt file. No apparent error was shown at the console, and i seek suggestions and help from all of the experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try json.dumps instead of load
2. Why do you wrap you dict in a list?
3. Write to file the result of the json.dumps, not the object

   ```
   with open(path, 'a+') as file:
       stringData = {"ContentUrl": link,
       "Text": post,
       "PublishDate": date.strip(),
       "Title": "",
       "SourceUrl": domainname,
       "SocialNetwork": media,
       "Source": "",
       "Author": name,
       "Like_count": likes.strip(),
       "Replies_count": replies.strip(),
       "Retweets_count": retweets.strip(),
       "Schema": "SOCIAL_MEDIA"}

       objData = json.dumps(stringData)
       file.write(objData)
   ```

Comment: Hi! I wrap it in a list mainly because i want each chunk of the data to be a set as there are many chunks in my .txt file.

Comment: I think this is superfluous, in your case every chunk will be the new string in a file. Look my answer update

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `json.load` correctly; try it like this:

```
record = {"ContentUrl": link,
    "Text": post,
    "PublishDate": date.strip(),
    "Title": "",
    "SourceUrl": domainname,
    "SocialNetwork": media,
    "Source": "",
    "Author": name,
    "Like_count": likes.strip(),
    "Replies_count": replies.strip(),
    "Retweets_count": retweets.strip(),
    "Schema": "SOCIAL_MEDIA"}  

with open(path, 'a') as file:
    objData = json.load(file)
    objData.append(record)
    file.write(json.dumps(objData))
```

Comment: Hi! I tried using the above method and i still have the same result. The data was not appended to the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the data to the list (`stringData`) and finally write the `stringData` to the second file using

```
stringData = [] #init

def addToDataToBeWritten(path, name, username, post, link, replies, retweets, likes, retweetby, date, domainname):    

    row = {"ContentUrl": link,
    "Text": post,
    "PublishDate": date.strip(),
    "Title": "",
    "SourceUrl": domainname,
    "SocialNetwork": media,
    "Source": "",
    "Author": name,
    "Like_count": likes.strip(),
    "Replies_count": replies.strip(),
    "Retweets_count": retweets.strip(),
    "Schema": "SOCIAL_MEDIA"}
    stringData.append(raw)

''' Read and call the method here'''
with open(path, 'w') as file:  
    file.write(json.dumps(stringData))
```